# Using Vue with Redactor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, redactor, redactor.js

I am using a v-model on Redactor. When I do this it returns "Event" not the actual data I'm looking for. Any ideas on how to return the correct data?

**HTML**

```
<div id="question-create-form">
  <textarea class="form-control question-create-editor" id="question_description" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#question-create-form .question-create-editor').redactor({
    imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
    plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
    buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
  });
  $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').attr('v-model', 'questionDescription');
```

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, see the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035340/jquery-plugin-in-vue-component-cannot-pass-value-to-prop/43035433?noredirect=1#43035433

Answer (score 3):

Redactor appears to be a jQuery widget, which means it works by manipulating the DOM. Vue expects to control the DOM, which means the two are going to step on each others' toes **unless** you confine your (Redactor's) DOM manipulations to the lifecycle hooks of a [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

To make your Redactor component [work with `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events), it will need to:

1. accept a `value` prop
2. emit an `input` event with the new value