# jQuery plugin in Vue component: Cannot pass value to prop

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, redactor

I have added the jquery redactor plugin in a vue component. The plugin is working fine but I need to access the html so I can see it in Vue.

I have tried everything I can think of, methods, computed properties but I can't find a way. It's particularly tricky because Redactor adds new html into the dom, and I need to get the data from the added html.

Currently I am getting this error, `this.$emit is not a function`. I need to get the html value of `.redactor-editor` into the prop so it will be available in the vue data. The var `textContent` prints out correctly in console but I can't get that to show in the `prop`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea class="form-control question-create-editor" id="question_description" placeholder="Go wild with all the details here - make image upload work" rows="3">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['redactorValue'],
    mounted: function(){
          $('#question-create-form .question-create-editor').redactor({
            imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
            plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
            buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
          });
    },
    computed: {
      redactorValue: function(){
        $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').on('keyup', function(){
          var textContent = $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').html();
          console.log( 'textContent = ' + textContent );
          this.$emit('redactorValue', textContent);
        });
      }
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<vueredactor></vueredactor>
```

Comment: Don't name the prop and the computed the same name. I expect that is the cause of your `this.$emit` is not a function issue.

Comment: Why not just specify a data value and use that instead of a prop? It seems like that's an internal value and not a property.

Comment: Thanks I changed that but it had no effect

Comment: Derp. I missed the callback. You need to call your function properly. I'll add an answer.

Comment: I tried using a prop, and the internalValue method you did on the other question didn't work here because redactor add new HTML into the dom so I can't use an event in the template because that html is not present into template. Thats why I am trying to get the HTML via the computed property and send it to the prop.

Comment: You can't change the prop from inside the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.$emit is not a function` issue is because `this` is pointing to the `window`.

Also I moved the `keyup` definition into `mounted`.

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            redactorValue: null
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
          $('#question-create-form .question-create-editor').redactor({
            imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
            plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
            buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
          });

          $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').on('keyup', function(){
              this.redactorValue = $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').html();
          }.bind(this));
    }
};
```

Comment: Your work is magnificent as usual. Thanks heaps!!! I had no idea about using `bind` inside the function.

Comment: Well, there are a number of ways to use the right `this`, that is just one. See this documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vue.js/9350/using-this-in-vue#t=201703262252360537653

Comment: Are you wanting to use `v-model` on this component? Is that way you wanted to `$emit` `redactorValue`?

Comment: I wanted to go the v-model route but then I couldn't find a way because the html I need to put it on is not in the template. BTW it has stopped working since you update the answer to use `refs` and `el`

Comment: I'll back those out. Ideally you would want to use those instead of jQuery. I just don't have something to play with to make sure it works.

Comment: You *should* be able to make it work with `v-model` by adding a value prop and emitting `input` when the editor changes. My concern is I'm not sure you want the value coming *in* from the outside. Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Cheers

Comment: Just a question regarding the v-model. How would it work if I'm getting the data from a div not an input? What would I emit instead of input?

Comment: @ClintonGreen You would still emit `input`. Like this, `this.$emit('input', reactorValue)`. That's what `v-model` will listen for unless you customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @BertEvans superb answer. Here is a solution that adds props and v-model back into the mix. This allows you to get the redactor content as a value and have access to that data in the root.

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea class="form-control question-create-editor" id="question_description" placeholder="Go wild with all the details here - make image upload work" rows="3">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      props: ['value'],
      data(){
          return {
              redactorValue: null
          }
      },
      mounted: function(){
            $('#question-create-form .question-create-editor').redactor({
              imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
              plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
              buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
            });

            $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').on('blur', function(){
                this.redactorValue = $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').html();
                this.$emit('input', this.redactorValue);
            }.bind(this));
      }
  };
</script>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('vueredactor', require('./components/redactor.vue'));

var App = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                  redactorContent: null
                }
            });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app>
    <vueredactor v-model="redactorContent"></vueredactor>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my working VueJS 2 component with Redactor Editor 3 from Imperavi.
Support multi-editor in same view, but editor need unique name/id.
Not require jQuery library.

**RedactorEditor.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="redactor">
    <textarea ref="redactorContainer" :id="id" :value="value"></textarea>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    import 'addons/redactor/css/redactor.css'
    import 'addons/redactor/redactor'
    //import 'addons/redactor/plugins/wordslimiter/wordslimiter'
    //import 'addons/redactor/plugins/beyondgrammar/beyondgrammar'

    export default {
        name: 'redactor-editor',
        props: {
            value: {
                required: true,
                twoWay: true
            },
            id: {
                type: String,
                default: 'editor'
            },
            minHeight: {
                type: String,
                default: '300px',
            },
            maxHeight: {
                type: String,
                default: '800px',
            },
            buttons: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => ['html', 'format', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', 'lists', 'link']
            },
            plugins: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            wordslimiter: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            beyondgrammarSettings: {
                type: Object,
                default: null
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                propValue: this.value
            }
        },
        created () {
            this.isChanging = false;
            this.app = null;
        },
        mounted () {
            var me = this;
            this.app = $R(this.$refs.redactorContainer, {
                style: true,
                breakline: false,
                shortcodes: false,
                pasteClean: true,
                autoparseImages: false,
                autoparseVideo: false,
                multipleUpload: false,
                clipboardUpload: false,
                pasteLinkTarget: '_blank',
                placeholder: 'Write your text here ...',
                minHeight: this.minHeight,
                maxHeight: this.maxHeight,
                buttons: this.buttons,
                plugins: this.plugins,
                wordslimiter: this.wordslimiter,
                beyondgrammar: this.beyondgrammarSettings,
                callbacks: {
                    start: function() {
                        // set initial data
                        this.source.setCode(me.propValue);
                    },
                    blur: function (e) {
                        // keyup not work with last typed text, fix sync with v-model by using blur
                        if (!me.isChanging) {
                            me.isChanging = true;
                            var code = this.source.getCode()
                            me.propValue = (code === null || code.length === 0 ? null : code);
                            me.$emit('input', me.propValue);
                            me.$nextTick(function() {
                                me.isChanging = false;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        destroyed () {
            this.app = $R(this.$refs.redactorContainer)
            if (this.app) {
                this.app.destroy()
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import RedactorEditor from './components/RedactorEditor.vue'

// app
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    data: {
       editorButtons: ['undo', 'redo', 'bold', 'italic', 'lists', 'link'],
       editorPlugins: [],
       beyondgrammarSettings: {}
       editorHTMLContent: '',
    },
    components: {
        RedactorEditor
    }
}
```

**HTML usage**

```
<redactor-editor
    v-model="editorHTMLContent"
    :text-value="editorHTMLContent"
    :id="'editor_1"
    :name="'editor_1"
    :plugins="editorPlugins"
    :buttons="editorButtons"
></redactor-editor>
```

Example with custom Validator using vee-validate: https://gist.github.com/matinfo/52214f7f34ce6b746b483f0f92e6b5e5

Answer (score 0):

FOR ANYONE WANTS TO DO EVENTS IN OTHER WAY

Even if You wanted to use $emit there There is another way by using EventBus
Just create a event-bus.js file and write this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus  = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

after it import it in your components

```
import EventBus from '/your path/event-bus.js';
```

and then You can Emit it

```
EventBus.emit('myevent','I am boy');
```

to receive it you don't have to specify the event name on receiving components prop

You simply can do this

```
EventBus.on('myevent',value=>{
console.log(value) // I am boy will be displayed
})
```